# Calling web service from Android App returns null object

Tags: android, null, wsdl, ksoap, propertyinfo

I'm writing an Android App that communicates with an web service using KSOAP. The connection between web service and Android app is working as I can call the webservice and get a return value (hello). But if I try to give a name from the App to the web service via .addProperty the webservice returns a null object.

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
private final String NAMESPACE_Local = "http://test.com/";  
    private final String URL_Local = "http://168.185.226.21:7001/myTest/myTestWebServiceService";
  private final String SOAP_ACTION_Local = "Hello_Action_Extend";
   private final String METHOD_NAME_Local = "hello_extend";

    public void LocalServer(View view)
    {
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.update_text);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_Local, METHOD_NAME_Local);
        request.addProperty("name", "Christian");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_Local);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_Local, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());


            text.setText(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Device or service offline",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

WebServer:

```
package com.test;

import javax.jws.*;

@WebService
public class myTestWebService {

    @WebMethod(action="Hello_Action") //that method works
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

    @WebMethod(action="Hello_Action_Extend")
    public String hello_extend(String name) //that works also, but it is giving back "hello null"
    {
        return "hello "+name;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
request.addProperty("name", "Christian");
```

for:

```
request.addProperty("name",ElementType.STRING_CLASS, "Christian");
```

and the response for:

```
SoapObject reponse=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
response.getProperty("name");
```

[API SoapObject](http://ksoap.objectweb.org/software/documentation/api/org/ksoap/SoapObject.html#getPropertyInfo%28int,%20org.kobjects.serialization.PropertyInfo%29)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately Eclipse is giving errors for each of your suggestions. For request.addProperty("name",ElementType.STRING_CLASS, "Christian"); is says STRING_CLASS cannot be resolved or is not a field.... For the second response.getProperty("name"); Eclipse wants to cast the response to either SoapObject or KvmSerializable, but neither works.